# Inconsistent pseudo random between c++ and c#

Tags: c#, c++

I'm attempting to convert a pseudo rand function from c++ to c# but it doesnt seem to return the correct values. Its important that i use a consistent set for encryption so i cant just use a random number.

this is the function in c++.

```
int get_pseudo_rand()
{
  return( ((_last_rand = _last_rand * 214013L
     + 2531011L) >> 16) & 0x7fff );
}
```

and this is my c# alternative

```
int get_pseudo_rand()
{
  return (((_last_rand = (_last_rand * 214013 + 2531011) >> 16) & 0x7fff));
}
```

I removed the Ls since c#s int data type is 4 bytes like c++ longs whereas c#s longs are 8 bytes.

the first time the function is run from the seed the answer is consistent with the c++ version but then it begins to diverge.

Any ideas?

Comment: The C++ code is missing a parenthesis somewhere. Also, can you clarify what type `_last_rand` is in each language. (And for C++, the size of that type on your paltform.) Also, if possible, the seed you are using and the first two random numbers on each platform.

Comment: Certainly, The seed is 1274653591 and its correctly set both times. In the C++ code the first two answers are 28818 and 20295. These are correct. In C# the first two results are 28818 and 28610. _last_rand is an int (4 bytes) in both languages. I am using a 32-bit program so the size of ints and longs in c++ should both be 4 bytes. (the missing bracket is inconsequential to the calculation)

Comment: You know, if you use temporary variables it would make your intent clearer, and would make this less subject to errors like you've found here.  Also, a good compiler (jitter) *should* optimize it out anyhow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have parenthesized the two statements in a different way that changes their meaning. The `C++` code updates `_last_rand` and then right-shifts the result, the `C#` code performs the right-shift before updating `_last_rand`. I've lined the statements up below to make the difference more obvious.

C++:

```
return (((_last_rand =  _last_rand * 214013L + 2531011L) >> 16) & 0x7fff);
```

C#:

```
return (((_last_rand = (_last_rand * 214013  + 2531011 ) >> 16) & 0x7fff));
```

Comment: +1 Confirmed. With the shift before the store, I get one set of answers. With the shift after the store, I get the other. This accounts for the difference.

Comment: @Steve: I want to emphasize that I think the `C++` code is more correct. If you right-shift __before__ updating your variable then "random" bits are being truncated away every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have parenthesized differentyl which leads to storing different values in `_last_rand`... with your code `_last_rand` stores 28818 after the first run... with the C++ code it stores 1888663550 which is the value BEFORE `>>` and before `&`. Thus it startes diverging from second run on...

To achieve the same behaviour as in C++ use in C#

```
return (((_last_rand =  _last_rand * 214013 + 2531011) >> 16) & 0x7fff);
```